# iOS: the difference between "Done" & "Save" when affirmatively completing a modal task

Tags: usability, buttons, ios, modal-view

In a modal view in iOS, the Apple provided (and localized) button titles to affirmatively complete the task and close the modal are "Add," "Done," and "Save."

The difference between "Add" and "Done" & "Save" makes sense; if an item is being edited, it already exists and "adding" implies it will be added again as a copy. I observed this in the iOS calendar app while adding a new event.

**What is the difference between "Done" and "Save"?**

In the Calendar app again, when editing an existing event the word "Done" is used as opposed to "Save." Either way the event still gets saved. Is there a subtle difference between the two?

[image: Editing an event in the iOS calendar app]

[This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45557/save-add-new-save-close-save-done-cancel) helped, however it did not specifically address the difference between "Done" and "Save" and it was not in the context of iOS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save ensures that the data you've entered is saved. If you **do not tap on Save, your new data won't be saved**. The original will remain.

Done exits the edit screen to ensure that the **Settings you've entered are right, but doesn't "save" anything for the future**. It might be possible that you will have to reenter the details for another transaction.

Bowen Li has already addressed this on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-if-any-between-Save-and-Done-for-UX-button-labeling) with examples. According to him however, **iOS broke the rule** by using Done instead of Save in contacts.